# auth0.js unable to get refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I am using **auth0-js**

```
const auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  domain: origin,
  clientID: cId,
  redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/cb`,
  responseType: 'code',
  scope: 'openid email profile offline_access',
});
auth.authorize();
```

In the callback, I am the only getting  access_token, idToken. But according to documentation for a refresh token, only add **offline_access** to scope. it will return a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I have to pass the **prompt** in auth.authorize({prompt: 'consent'})